# Excel Lookup list partial match

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets.

Sheet 1 is the work sheet:

```
SONY KDL55W805CBAEP LED TV (Flat, 55 Zoll, FullHD, 3D, SMART TV, Android TV)
SONY KDL75W855CBAEP LED TV (Flat, 75 Zoll, FullHD, 3D, SMART TV, Android TV)
SONY KDL48W705CBAEP LED TV (Flat, 48 Zoll, FullHD, SMART TV)
SONY KD43X8305CBAEP LED TV (Flat, 43 Zoll, UHD 4K, SMART TV, Android TV)
SONY KDL50W756C LED TV (Flat, 50 Zoll, FullHD, SMART TV, Android TV)
```

Sheet 2 contains the full model reference numbers:

```
KDL55W805CBAEP
KDL75W855CBAEP
KDL48W705CBAEP
KD43X8305CBAEP
KDL50W756CBAEP
```

I'm using `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15;SEARCH(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$114;Sheet1![Row #]),Sheet2!$B$1:$B$114);"")`

Everything gets match as long as the text in Sheet 1 is a 100% match.
But as soon as it isn't I don't get a match.

For example.

Sheet 1:

```
SONY KDL50W756C LED TV (Flat, 50 Zoll, FullHD, SMART TV, Android TV)
```

Sheet2:

```
KDL50W756CBAEP
```

How can I make those match aswell?

EDIT:

This is sheet 1:

[image: Sheet1]

This is sheet 2:

So in column `item_model` I want the full model reference.
But as not all references in Sheet 1 match 100% with Sheet 2 I have a problem

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: are those separate columns or all in one column?

Comment: apparently its all in one column...item_2_name

Comment: Now that we know that the description is all in one cell, is the model ref always the second "word" in string on sheet1?  If not then this will need to be in vba.

Comment: @findwindow the master has arrived!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula if the Model number is always the second "Word":

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(TRIM(MID("*" & SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)) & "*",Sheet2!B:B,0)),"")
```

[image]

---

EDIT: In Dutch, I think

```
=ALS.FOUT(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B;VERGELIJKEN(SPATIES.WISSEN(MIDDEN("*" & SUBSTITUEREN(B2;" ";HERHALING(" ";99));99;99)) & "*";Sheet2!B:B;0));"")
```

I may have some typos or missing `)`

Comment: IFERROR, INDEX, MATCH, TRIM, MID, SUBSTITUTE, REPT  are the excel function that would need translating to your local dialect.  Also look at potentially changing  a coma (,) to a semi colon (;) depending on what your system uses for separators.

Comment: I'm using 2016 in Dutch :( I'm just installing the English language pack

Comment: I am a Canuck and unfortunately I do not know "Hollish" as my cousin once said!  Now if you need it in french I MIGHT be able to help you. 8)  You should not have any issues with 2016.

Comment: @Wouter what are the actual names of the sheets?  You will need to replace `Sheet2` with the name of the sheet that you are showing as "Sheet 2"

Comment: @ScottCraner, Works perfect now :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @ScottCraner  Now I am truly impressed, your are now "Formulating" in other languages!  Nice work.

Comment: @Wouter the reference B2 in the formula is the reference to Sheet 1 Cell B2.  It does not matter the order on Sheet 2.  It will find the second "word" in Cell B2 and compare it to Column B in Sheet2 till it finds a match.

Comment: @Wouter make sure you did not put a sheet reference in front of the B2.  The only sheet references should be in front of the B:B.

Comment: @ForwardEd google is your friend "English to Dutch Excel formula" and I found a cool list.

Comment: @ScottCraner...100% correct with your Dutch :) Dank je wel :)

Answer (score 2):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,IF(AGGREGATE(14,6,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,$A$1:$A$6))*ROW(A1:A6)),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,$A$1:$A$6))*ROW(A1:A6)),1),-1)),"not found")
```

You will have to update the ranges to suit your needs.

C1 what you are looking for.
First A1:A5  what you are looking in.
B1:B6  what you want to return.
Row(A1:A5) is acting as a counter and may need adjusting if your data is not in the first row.

Tossed in some error generation and checking in case the item you were looking for is not in the list.

[image: proof of concept]

This will work as long as what you are searching for is not so short as to be found  partially after the start in the string.  if you loosk at my example if you searked for K it would toss in the result from row 6 because K is found within the text in A6

In light of the edits

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,IF(AGGREGATE(14,6,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(C1,FIND(" ",C1)+1,FIND(" ",C1,FIND(" ",C1)+1)-FIND(" ",C1)-1),$A$1:$A$6))*ROW(A1:A6)),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(C1,FIND(" ",C1)+1,FIND(" ",C1,FIND(" ",C1)+1)-FIND(" ",C1)-1),$A$1:$A$6))*ROW(A1:A6)),1),-1)),"not found")
```

This assumes what you are searching for is always between the first and second space in the item name.

Comment: If you build it, he will come...If you get it wrong, the master will show you the error of your ways.

Comment: I've edited my question as I think we misunderstood each other :( Sheet 1 is the first tab of the excel file and sheet2 the second tab of the file

Comment: that part I got, and why I said you would have to edit the cell references to suit your data.  The problem is, I thought SONY, KDL..., LED, TV, etc were all in separate columns.  The problem now is we need to strip out the part you are looking up from the rest of the text in the column

Comment: @findwindow  I accidently sniped an accepted answer from scott earlier today with a really bad answer.  I made it overly verbose!  I eventually posted to the OP to unaccept my answer and give it to scott.  Was kind of funny

Comment: I think that is only because Scott was slow with the post.  I think he has the better more concise answer...one of these days I will wrap my head around that add a huge space and pull out the word separateing the spaces technique.  Scott and Jeeped like that technique

Comment: @findwindow you mean tigeravatar changes the accepted answer too? 8)...this one was changed and rightly so.  I just layed the ground work for Scott...at least that is what I will keep telling myself

Comment: It's never about the check mark or the points, It is about giving the OP options.  How they choose or what works best for them is what matters.  IF your "verbose" answers better communicate to the OP then it should be the one that is selected.

Comment: It is the most concise method I have found to find specific words with formulas. @findwindow

Comment: @ScottCraner I agree with the checks and point do not matter and giving the OP options.  I do not agree that a more verbose method should be the accepted answer when there is something much more concise.  We should be building efficiencies.  Hence why offset answer are not preferred.  But in the end its really up to the OP what they feel best suits their needs.

Comment: @findwindow we are referring to code [in this case actually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194656/excel-logical-formula-for-total-when-there-are-two-types-of-null-values/37194954#37194954)

Comment: @ScottCraner, All my fields return empty...as in no results...Maybe I've made a mistake in translating your formule as my excel is in Dutch :(

Comment: @Wouter see the post I made under scott's answer  The only other thing I was gong to say is which version of excel are you using.  But apparently that should not be an issue.

Comment: @ForwardEd, it did make a difference. First of all I had to change the coma (,) to a semi colon (;) and when I put the formule in English I got errors. So now install the english language pack

Comment: @findwindow, assuming scott's points are at 18800 for today.  if you and I up vote each of his answers and they are also the accepted answer, then for 6 questions a day and in a 406 days, scott can get a free coffee cup!  sonner if he answers bounties and/or his point total is higher 8)

Comment: @findwindow search what can happen when your rep exceeds 100K  With 200 a day cap barring bounties the quickest you can do it in is 500 days.  So take the value of a coffee cup and divide it by 8 hours a day times 500 days and that is how much we get paid to work here...I mean volunteer here 8)

Comment: @wouter  best to put questions about Scotts questions under scotts answer.  If I decided to delete this question in the future all comments would disappear too which might make figuring out how scotts answer was finalized a little difficult

Comment: Just put the questions under Scott his answer...everything works brilliant now so I can sleep wel now :) Thank you for all your help